# Neural Network not identifying correct pattern

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, neural-network, xor, backpropagation

I have a neural network that contains 2 input neurons, 1 hidden layer containing 2 neurons, and one output neuron. I am using this neural network for the XOR problem, but it does not work.

***Test Results:***

If you test **1, 1** you get the output of **-1 (equivalent to 0)**.

If you test **-1, 1** you get the output of **1**.

If you test **1, -1** you get the output of **1**.

If you test **-1, -1** you get the output of **1**.

This last test is obviously incorrect, therefore my neural network is clearly wrong somewhere.

The exact output are [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpDWF.png)
So as you can see, changing 1, 1 to -1, -1 just flips the output value
And changing -1, 1 to 1, -1 does the same. This is obviously incorrect.

***These are the steps my neural network goes through:***

- Randomly assign the weights between -1, 1
- Forward propagate through the network (applying the tanh activation function to the hidden neurons and the output neuron)
- Back propagate using the algorithm explained at this website: https://stevenmiller888.github.io/mind-how-to-build-a-neural-network/ (is this algorithm correct?)

I need to know if I am ***missing something in my neural network***, and I was also wondering if anyone knew of a ***tutorial for back propagation that is less mathematical and more pseudo-code style***.

Also, I am **not** using biases or momentum within my neural network, so I was wondering if adding either of them would fix the issue?

I have tried a few different back propagation algorithms and none of them seem to work, so it is most likely not that.

Thanks for any help you can provide,

**Finley Dabinett.**

**UPDATE**:

I have added biases to the hidden and output layer and I get these results:

1,   1 = -1   - Correct

-1,  -1 = 1    - Incorrect

-1,   1 = 1    - Correct

1,  -1 = 1    - Correct

Comment: just add biases and you will be fine. They not "addons", they are **crucial** bits in neural nets.

Comment: @lejlot Do biases just act as extra inputs that have a constant value of 1 or -1?

Comment: @lejlot And should I apply them to just the hidden layer or the output layer as well?

Comment: you should have a bias in each layer (depending on your notation this means a bias in input and in a hidden layer or in hidden and output). "Additional inputs" is a good understanding for the input layer, for hidden it is less obvious but you can still think about it as an extra neuron always producing 1.

Comment: @lejlot And the weights of the bias' get back propagated too?

Comment: yes, otherwise it would change nothing. I mean you do back prop **to** them, there is nowhere to backprop **from** them

Comment: @lejlot I have added bias to the hidden layer and the output layer and I have back propagated their weights. These are the results I am getting now: https://i.gyazo.com/51b3465613f2a3cbc56c48d29bb72cdd.png

Comment: I have trained it multiple times and I always get similar outputs to this one. So I think I may have missed something else. What is the most simple back propagation tutorial you know of?

Comment: I think you are missing nothing, must be an implementation issue. If you could provide us with the code which we can run, we could help more.

Comment: @TamasHegedus sketch.js: http://pastebin.com/YgWjGgG5 layers.js: http://pastebin.com/7fRW8gQy

Comment: It requires the p5.js library to run. Unless you can just look at it and work out what it's doing. Also, sorry for the bad programming and bad layout, I started writing it a while back when I was new to it so it's a bit all over the place.

Comment: @TamasHegedus any luck finding the issue?

Comment: @FinleyDabinett Yeah sry it was late night in Hungary :) No need to apologize, your code is pretty clean. Although I did not manage to get your code work but found something: In the train function you only use the first three datapoints. `data[i % 3][0]` should be `data[i % 4]`. This causes some issues for sure, lets see if there are others.

Comment: @TamasHegedus I've managed to fix it and it now works for XOR. But, it does not work with real life applications.

Comment: What real life applications and what network shape are we talking about?

Comment: @TamasHegedus I'm using a 2-2-1 neural network and I'm training it for the sinx function. But my outputs are either random or all the same value. I am using the same code that I used for my xor (which works), just different data.

Comment: @TamasHegedus I have now completely fixed my neural network. The issue I was having in the first problem was my weights were being used in the wrong order. Then I had to change my backprop algorithm from my original one. Thanks for your help guys.